# How to move objects between two S3 buckets faster than a copy operation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, ceph

I need move some files between buckets, but move operation has behind the scenes operation copy. Copy isn’t suitable for me, because high cost and time. Any other options to change bucket for object?

Comment: I assume you're copying between regions? i.e. your two buckets are in different regions?

Comment: Is this a one off task or an ongoing one? Are you using the AWS CLI SDK or another method? Are you copying between regions or the same region?  You could look into using the sync method - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/move-objects-s3-bucket/

Comment: I use library com.amazon.aws.services.s3 and after reading the amazon documentation, i couldn‘t find any method “move” objects except copy. I just need relocate objects between buckets and thought there might be another way. For examlpe change key object without cocopying object data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to "move" objects between Amazon S3 buckets is to copy them (and optionally delete the original object).

If you wish to copy *many* objects, then the copies can be performed **in parallel**, which reduces the elapsed time to copy the objects.

If you are merely wanting the fastest copy time of a *single* object, then the only option is to start the copy quicker (since the copy itself can't be sped-up). Using [Amazon S3 Replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication.html) would be the fastest option because it would perform the copy very soon after the object is created.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [S3 replication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication.html). It works cross and inter-region way for now. There are another options like lambda, glue, data pipeline and others ... depends on particular use-case and budget